# "x" is not a function at

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

I keep getting an error message that:

> check is not a function at area question 1

[image: check is not a function at area question 1]

and

> check is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick

[image: check is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick]

and I think this is the reason that the check() function is not running.  I've looked at so many other solutions to this problem but none of them are really helpful for my issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var number1;
var number2;
var response;
var calcanswer;
var score = 0;
window.onload = areaquestion1;
score.innerHTML = "SCORE: " + score;

function areaquestion1() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/2_1.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("width", "700");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("height", "400");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "2_1");
    document.getElementById('img').appendChild(imageBlock); // this appends it to the bottom of the page
    number1 = 2
    number2 = 1
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";  
    document.getElementById("check").check();
}
function areaquestion2() {
    var imageBlock = document.createElement("img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("id", "img");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("src", "Images/4_2.png");
    imageBlock.setAttribute("alt", "4_2");
    document.body.appendChild(imageBlock); // this appends it to the bottom of the page
    number1 = 4
    number2 = 2
    calcanswer = (number1*number2);
    var question = document.getElementById("question");
    question.innerHTML = "What is the area of this lego brick?";
    document.getElementById("solve").check();
}


function check() {
    var statusDiv = document.getElementById("status");
    response=document.getElementById("answer").value;

    if(response != calcanswer)
    statusDiv.innerHTML="Incorrect";
    else
    if (response==calcanswer)
    {
        statusDiv.innerHTML="Very good!";
        score ++;
        document.getElementById("score").textContent = score
        document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
        
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Lego Area Play</title>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/gridtest.css">
    <script src="JavaScript/Play.js"></script>
  </head>
<body onload="areaquestion1();">
  
  <div class="header">
    <h1>LEGO AREA</h1>
    <p>Calculating <b>area</b> with Emmet.</p>
    <div id="scorelabel"><label>SCORE:</label></div>
    <div id="score" class="score"></div>
  </div>


<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <div id="question"></div>
      <div id="img"></div>
      <div id="status"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <div id ="prompt"></div>
        <label>Area = </label>
        <input type="text" id="answer" placeholder="Answer"/>
        <label>Units<sup>2</sup></label>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
        <input id="check" type="button" value="CHECK!" onclick="check()" />
        <div class="practice"> <a href="Practice.html"><img src="Images/legoBlue2.png" id="practicebtn" alt="lego button for practice page" width=350px height=140px></a></div>
        <div class="menu"> <a href="LegoWelcome.html"><img src="Images/menured.png" id="menubtn" alt = "lego button for menu page" width=350px height=140px></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `check` function is declared on global scope and not defined in `HTMLBaseElement.prototype`. You will need to allow check to accept the element as argument instead

Comment: You have `check` as a method in the click handler of the button. That doesn't magically assign a new property to the button called `check`. What exactly are you attempting here?

Comment: This line in the areaquestion1 and areaquestion2 methods: `document.getElementById("solve").check();` is what is causing the second error. The first error is because the second error prevents the loading of the check method, which means that when you click on the check button there is no check method defined. Fix the second error, which is the `document.getElementById("solve").check();`, and both errors should disappear if nothing else is wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `prototype`s. Put an argument that takes a DOM node into your `check` function.

Comment: Once the CHECK! button has been clicked, the function check() should be run for the first question.  Could you give some fixed example code for me to look at?

Answer (score 0):

As Cannicide pointed out, your second error occurs when the `arequestion1()` is called on load, on the line `document.getElementById("check").check();`

You added the check method to `onclick`, but that did not add a new property to the button.

Your first error is a little more complicated. This is the simplest recreation of your error I tried creating.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>

  <script>
  function f(){
    console.log("f run")
  }
  </script>

<!--   id same as function name -->
  <input id="f" type="button" value = "B1" onclick="f()" />
    
<!--   button inside a form -->
  <form>
    <input type="button" value = "B2" onclick="f()" />
  </form>

<!--   button inside a form with random id -->
  <form>
    <input id="somethingelse" type="button" value = "B3" onclick="f()" />
  </form>
  
<!--   button inside a form, equal id and method name -->
  <form>
    <input id="f" type="button" value = "B4" onclick="f()" />
  </form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

There are 4 buttons, each with small difference in its environment. Notice how only the button that is inside a form and has the same id name and the onclick method name throws you an error.

To this error I unfortunately have no clue to why and how does this happen.
If someone here knows what is going on here, please explain!
cheers :)